# Maximum video out resolution of iPad Mini?

Tags: ios, uiscreen, ipad-mini

I'm developing an iPad app that can employ an external monitor. When I plug my iPad 3 into my external monitor, I get back a list of resolutions from the external UIScreen object that includes 1920x1080.

When I do the same with my iPad mini, the max resolution I get back is 1600x900.

This would make me think the iPad mini doesn't support full HD external video, but the Apple specs say this:

> Video mirroring and video out support: Up to 1080p through Lightning
>   Digital AV Adapter and Lightning to VGA Adapter (adapters sold
>   separately)

...which seems pretty unambiguous that it should support full HD.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling with the same thing. Any luck? Additionally, if you go in Safari and play a video it stretches to full screen; when I output my app to the screen I get a black border around the 1600x900 max resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad mini does not HAVE the resolution for 1080p (it has 1024x768 screen resolution while 1080p is 1920x1080 as you mentioned), hence, mirroring does not make sense.

Video playback, on the other hand, should work.

Comment: The resolution of the built-in iPad display doesn't make a difference. Even the iPad mini, in my broken case I mentioned, is still supporting 1600x900 resolution on the external monitor, which is higher than the 1024x768 it supports internally. Apps can display different content on a 1920x1080 external monitor, and can support the full resolution on that external monitor. (As I mentioned, it works great on an iPad 3.) And Apple's own specs say the iPad mini outputs 1080p.

Answer (score 0):

TV resolution can be set in Settings>General>TV Out.

The max resolution shown in that menu is your iPhone or iPad's screen resolution.